# PHP MVC - creating a complex website

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a website in a complex way in php codeigniter. I wrote a hypothetical example down below to make my point.
Something like this:
[www.example.com/bmw/cars/suv/X3/options][1]
or
[www.example.com/honda/motorcycle/trial/montesacota/options][2]

So all I know , I should write a controller for each manufacturer. like bmw or honda ... 
and then write some methods for them like cars, motorcycles, boats...
in the next step what should I do, I mean the next 3 parameters? 
It would be so hard to put them all as parameters of a method.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Is it the URLs you absolutely want or what you think you should do ?
You should take a look at routes.

Answer (score 0):

try controller honda for example

inside honda controller try this

```
public function honda($vehicletype, $trial, $model, $year /* etc */ ) {

echo $vehicle;
echo $trial;
echo $model;
echo $year;

}
```

suppose url is like

[www.example.com/honda/motorcycle/trial/montesacota/2015]

this will return:

motorcycle
trial
montesacota
2015

hope this helps or elaborate more..